# How to resolve unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, connection-timeout

I changed hibernate timeout settings as well as idle time but it not working
My hibernate properties are

```
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300000</property>
```

And, I'm getting following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator$1.getNextValue(TableGenerator.java:530)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator.generate(TableGenerator.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at com.ihealthmantra.upload.com.ihealthmantra.customer.upload.service.SellerUploadImpl.lambda$4(SellerUploadImpl.java:801)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.ihealthmantra.upload.com.ihealthmantra.customer.upload.service.SellerUploadImpl.createTimeSlotUploadedSeller(SellerUploadImpl.java:738)
    at com.ihealthmantra.upload.com.ihealthmantra.customer.upload.service.SellerUploadImpl.populateSlot(SellerUploadImpl.java:1146)
    at com.ihealthmantra.upload.App.main(App.java:81)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 820,677 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 820,679 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3746)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2509)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2480)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4811)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:912)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:48)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

It was working fine earlier, but as data grown recently, it started throwing above exception.

Comment: Code was working fine previosly

Answer (score 0):

> ... the server was 820,679 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server
>   configured value of 'wait_timeout'...

It seems like connection to database server is taking longer time than the value set for timeout. And it was mentioned in your exception as well.

To resolved this issue, either you can increase timeout value or pass `autoReconnect=true` with your `JDBC` string (as mentioned in your exception)

To change `wait_timeout` value in MySQL, you could refer existing post.

[MySQL wait_timeout Variable - GLOBAL vs SESSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440336/mysql-wait-timeout-variable-global-vs-session)

**OR**

Append `autoReconnect=true` to your JDBC url string

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exodb?autoReconnect=true
```

Comment: thanx ravi, I have used ?autoReconnect=true option yet it throwing same error.

Comment: @HanumantGawali Then change the value for `wait_timeout `. Also, you should be proactive when you post your question. Don't forget after posting the question. Make sure, we get the conclusion ASAP.

Comment: I changed wait_timeout from 3000 to 1000000 yet having same issue .

Comment: <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1000000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000000</property>
        <property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
  <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
  <property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>

Comment: @HanumantGawali it is supposed to be changed at server not your config file and `timeout` isn't same as `wait_timeout`